# Passar ID do PHP por javascript para uma página

Tags: php, javascript

Eu gostaria de enviar o id que eu pego com o php e enviar para uma página a cada 30 segundos...o que eu fiz até agora:

```
$idtarefa = $_GET['id'];
```

recebo o id, faço todo o html e ai no javascript eu fiz isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {

                // Tudo correu bem NA REQUISIÇÃO!

            } else {
                // debug:
                console.log(ajax);
                alert('Erro na requisição.');
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        ajax.open('get', 'atualiza_base2.php?id=<?php echo $idtarefa ?>');
        ajax.send();
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

A ideia é que atualize a hora a cada 30 segundos de acordo com a id em uma tabela mysql, eu olhei vários scripts e fui até ai, mas com certeza tem algo errado que eu não sei o que é...no arquivo atualiza_base eu queria pegar o id com get dnv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte.
Antes de incluir ou escrever o código javascript, definir uma constante com o seu id, exemplo:

```
<script>
    const idTarefa = <?php echo $idTarefa ?>;
</script>
```

E seu setInterval ficará assim:

```
setInterval(function() {
    ajax.open('get', 'atualiza_base2.php?id='+idTarefa);
    ajax.send();
}, 3000);
```

Para pegar o id novamente, basta fazer `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Caso não tenha sanado sua dúvida, dê mais detalhes sobre o arquivo atualiza_base.php

Comment: cara, não funcionou...:T

Comment: Pior que isso é a chave de todo um sistema...e não consigo passar essa id, batendo pino a 2 dias já

Comment: Pode dar mais informações sobre o erro e como está sendo implementado?